# A hard inequality (for me)

Tags: inequality

For $n \in N$; $n \geq 2$ and $x \in R$

Prove:
$-(1+x^2)^n \leq (2x)^n+(1-x^2)^n \leq (1+x^2)^n$

I have no clue to do.
Help please, thank you so much

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inequality $(2x)^n + (1-x^2)^n \le (1+x^2)^n$ is equivalent to
$$(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})^n + (\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})^n  \le 1.$$
Put $x = \tan \frac{t}2$. We have to prove that
$$sin^n t + \cos^n t \le 1.$$

As $|\sin t|, |\cos t| \le 1$ we have
$$sin^n t + \cos^n t \le |sin^n t| + |\cos^n t| \le |sin^2 t| + |\cos^2 t| = 1.$$

It's easy to show that $(2x)^n + (1-x^2)^n \ge -(1+x^2)^n$ by the same argument.